# The system cannot find the file specified in bash

Tags: windows, cmd

I am trying to run SIFT descriptor in windows. There are a large number of files, so instead of running one by one I am trying to run iteratively for all the files in a directory. I am using the following command:

```
 `for %i in (*.pgm) do siftWin32 <%~i.pgm >%~ni.key`
```

`siftwin32` is a binary executable file and is present in the folder. I am in the current directory. I use `dir` to see if it is present and it is being listed. but when I run the command I am getting an error saying the system cannot find the file specified.

How to give the path in the command ?

Comment: To assign this question to bash is not suitable. Any suggestions? `Windows shell` or `powershell` ?

Answer (score 1):

The command is not failing because it cannot find siftWin32; it is failing because it cannot find the .pgm file for the redirection.

The `%i` variable already contains the `.pgm` extension, so it fails when you concatenate a second extension.

```
for %i in (*.pgm) do siftWin32 <"%i" >"%~ni.key"
```